# Why does going under water and resurfacing heal Ty the Tasmanian Tiger?

Tags: ty-the-tasmanian-tiger

I've always thought it was a strange concept. If you slice your hand or lose an arm, dipping yourself in water doesn't heal you, so...where does this concept come from? Does it relate to the mythos surrounding Bunyips? Is there Aboriginal folklore about the healing properties of water?

The GameFAQs [walkthrough](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/561338-ty-the-tasmanian-tiger/faqs/20597) briefly mentions it as a tip early on without elaboration. Later in the walkthrough, it says:

> "If you go underwater and come back up, you'll receive your health back thanks to a small but helpful glitch in the game. This is similar to the glitch in the all-time favorite "Mario 64", perhaps it's an homage?"

The author first seemed to state with certainty that this was a glitch, but then suggested that it could have been included on purpose.

### So is this a glitch, or is this intentional?

I did not find any relevant information in IGN's [walkthrough](https://www.ign.com/articles/2004/03/01/ty-the-tasmanian-tiger-walkthrough-475365).

Visiting [The Cutting Room Floor](https://tcrf.net/Ty_the_Tasmanian_Tiger)'s page for Ty the Tasmanian Tiger, I learned some cool things but did not find any relevant information.

This [Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=650439499) contains the same tip without elaboration.

The [game manual](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Sony_Playstation_2/Manual/formated/Ty_the_Tasmanian_Tiger_-_2002_-_Electronic_Arts.pdf) mentions on page 7 breathing and not staying underwater indefinitely, and on page 10 it mentions that the breath meter functions underwater the same as the health meter, but it does not specify regarding the breath meter replenishing the above-water health meter.

Unsure where else to look, my question remains: **Why does going underwater and resurfacing heal Ty the Tasmanian Tiger?** *(Is this a glitch, or is this intentional?--and if it's intentional, where does the concept of water-dipping for healing come from?)*

Comment: I don't know about Ty the Tasmanian Tiger, but as far as Mario 64 is concerned, I believe this was intentional rather than a glitch. Since Mario 64 didn't have a dedicated air gauge, Mario's health bar acted as an air gauge, showing how long he could stay underwater. As a result, his health had to be restored whenever he surfaced. Mario 64 may have pioneered 3D platformers, but air gauges should've been relatively common by the time the PS2 came out. For example, Ocarina of Time and Banjo-Kazooie/Tooie had dedicated air gauges, and the all released on the N64 as well.